# Console.Beep() in stereo

Tags: windows, audio

On my laptop, I have many windows on my extended desktop (2 x 1920 x 1080) with some hidden behind others. (I also have a nice sound system.) Whenever a running job emits a beep, it takes me a while to hunt down the source.

Is it possible for a stereo beep that depends on the location of the window emitting the beep?

In general, shouldn't Microsoft build a configuration option for audio from an app to be positioned always relative to the center or relative to the location of the app window? Now when I am watching a YouTube in a window on the far right, the sound is always stereo wrt to center.

Comment: Wait, so are you talking about Console.Beep or about YouTube or about audio in general?

Comment: Looking for a directional console beep first, specifically.